# Drawing a graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text file that looks the following way:

```
14:49:15
0.00152897834778
14:49:22
0.00193500518799
14:49:29
0.00154614448547
14:49:36
0.0024299621582
14:49:43
0.00161910057068
14:49:50
0.00165987014771
14:49:57
0.00150108337402
```

I want to create a graph using the plot() method in which i wish every odd line from the text file to be a coordinate on the x axis and every non-odd line to be a y-axis coordinate to it's respective x(the line before the non-odd)
In this particular case  14:49:15 would be the first x and 0.00152897834778 the first y

Comment: Well, good luck with that.... But seriously, show your attempts.

Comment: I wish i had something to show

Comment: Then this question is not ready for SO. You first need to attempt this yourself and then if you get stuck come back with a specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may split the input by linebreaks `.split("\n")` and convert every second one to a datetime object. Then using `plt.plot_date()` gives you a plot showing the times.

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = u"""14:49:15
0.00152897834778
14:49:22
0.00193500518799
14:49:29
0.00154614448547
14:49:36
0.0024299621582
14:49:43
0.00161910057068
14:49:50
0.00165987014771"""

# split the string by linebreaks
l = u.split("\n")
# take every second substring and convert it to datetime 
x = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S") for i in l[::2] ]
# take every second substring starting at the second one
y = l[1::2]

plt.plot_date(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,it's just what i needed but for some reason my time increments every second and has a suffix "EET" , any idea why?

Comment: Now it's getting interesting. What is your matplotlib version? Can you print `plt.rcParams["timezone"]` and report what it says? You might want to use a `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter` like: `import matplotlib.dates;
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))` and see if it changes.

Comment: when printing plt.rcParams["timezone"] i get UTC,btw all the dates are rly cluttered together and i literally can't see anything is there a way to make intervals between them?

Comment: Let me repeat myself: What is your matplotlib version? What happens if you use a `DateFormatter`? Does the "EET" go away?

Comment: my matplotlib version is '0.99.1.1' and when try using `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFor‌​matter("%H:%M:%S")) `(import matplotlib.dates as mdates)i get a  `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFor‌​matter("%H:%M:%S"))
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Matplotlib 0.99 is exactly 8 years old. We are now at version 2.0.2. You may simply update your matplotlib. Since the documentation of version 0.99 isn't even online any more, there is little I can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the datetimes to numeric and plot them

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import datetime

string = """14:49:15
0.00152897834778
14:49:22
0.00193500518799
14:49:29
0.00154614448547
14:49:36
0.0024299621582
14:49:43
0.00161910057068
14:49:50
0.00165987014771"""

x = string.split('\n')[::2]
x = matplotlib.dates.date2num([datetime.datetime.strptime(xi, '%H:%M:%S') for xi in x])
y = np.array(string.split('\n')[1::2], dtype=float)

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: is it possible for the dates to be converted back from numerics to dates after the plot?